# segmentation fault with large number of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-ptr, virtual-destructor, make-shared

this I is my .h file:

```
class Node
    {
        
    public:
        static void disp(const std::vector<int> &v);
        static size_t Node_no;
        Node(const std::vector<int> & initial_state);
        ~Node();
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> val;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> up;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> down;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> right;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> left;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> parent;
    };
```

this is my node constructor that resets all pointer and increases number of nodes by 1;

```
Board::Node::Node(const std::vector<int> &initial_state)
{
    val = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(move(initial_state));
    this->right.reset();
    this->left.reset();
    this->up.reset();
    this->down.reset();
    this->parent.reset();
    Node::Node_no++;
}
```

this is I my destructor that just decrease number of nodes by static variable No_nodes

```
Board::Node::~Node()
{
    if(Node::Node_no%10==0)
        std::cerr << "Node destructor:"<<Node::Node_no << std::endl;
    Node::Node_no--;
}
```

and this one is my main file

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<int> init_vec = {2, 4, 6, 5, 8, 3, 0, 1, 7};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Board::Node>> ve;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) //120000
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Board::Node> vv = std::make_shared<Board::Node>(std::vector<int>({2, 4, 6, 5, 8, 3, 0, 1, 7}));
        if (ve.size() >= 1)
        {
            vv->down = ve[ve.size() - 1];
            vv->up = ve[ve.size() - 1];
            vv->right = ve[ve.size() - 1];
            vv->left = ve[ve.size() - 1];
            vv->parent = ve[ve.size() - 1];
        }
        ve.push_back(vv);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the problem occurs when I change this line in main file

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) //120000
```

to this :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 120000; i++) //120000
```

I get segmentation fault
any idea?

Comment: No errors logged with the segmentation fault? What happens when you let it fault when running under the debugger, or load the core file into the debugger?

Comment: `move(initial_state)` - moving from `const ref` is never a good idea. But probably not a source of this bug.

Comment: @Useless thanks for your reply . I don't receive any error  logged with segment fault. I use docker gcc:9.2.0 .

Comment: You should also install `gdb` and learn to use that. There's lots of information in core files!

Comment: The code shown, while not the best, doesn't appear like it will lead to a segfault. The issue is likely in code you haven't shown.

Comment: @Quimby could you plz tell me why it's not  good?

Comment: @AndyG . no this is all the code . is it possible that problem happens because of docker ?

Comment: @ali: It could very well be... you may need to increase your heap size.

Comment: There's a lot of memory in use here, even if it's all on the heap. And a ton of fragmentation.

Comment: AndyG I tried the command--memory="6g" for running docker but nothing chagned

Comment: @Yksisarvinen what should I do ?

Comment: thanks to @Useless i got following error using GDB                                                                                                                                 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000403cf2 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count (
    this=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7feff8>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:727
727     /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: No such file or directory.

Comment: `ve[ve.size() - 1]` is `ve.back()`.

Comment: `val = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(move(initial_state));` There is no sense of making shared_ptr to vector, this gets an unique copy of initial_state on the heat.

Comment: @ali Because it is useless at best, you cannot move from constant objects and users are not very accustomed to `const T&&` parameters since there are very few uses for them. But it could lead to unexpected calls if some library has use for const rvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know why this issue happens. Each futher element owns the previous element via `shared_ptr`. So when being deleted the first element's destructor calls the second element's destructor, then second element's destructor calls third element's destructor and so on until your stack is overflowed.

To fix this you should avoid using `shared_ptr` inside your `Node` class. Just store a link to next/prev node via raw pointer and delete nodes by external code (in fact you have your `ve` vector which can be responsible for storing nodes).

Comment: No idea why you got a downvote, but this is a correct answer, seeing the comment from OP. They get a crash in a `std::shared_ptr` destructor. 120000 destructor chain can well overflow a typical stack.

Comment: my problem is solved with your help . but can you tell me is there anyway to use other smart pointer, to avoid using delete keyword?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks. @ali you can use non owning smart pointers like `std::weak_ptr`. With `weak_ptr` you can check if the object is still alive prior using it. But raw pointers are also completely fine here.

Comment: dear @Yksisarvinen as @otter said, my program causes stack overflow but my question is : " the latest an object is created , sooner it will be deleted . so the last created object should be destructed first , and resets it's own `shared_ptr`  to nullptr so this object is not responsible for the rest of objects's   `shared_ptr` .